# The requested URL /quickstart/public/task was not found on this server

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel. I m following the basic task list project. When I m adding a task, I m getting the following error.

The requested URL /quickstart/public/task was not found on this server.

My route for adding a task is:

```
Route::post('/task', function(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), ['name' => 'required|max:255',]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect('/')
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $task = new Task;
    $task->name = $request->name;
    $task->save();
    return redirect('/');
});
```

Please help

Comment: Posted the proper solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248223/laravel-5-2-quickstart-guide-gives-not-found-error/40993429#40993429)

Answer (score 0):

You're using web server with wrong configuration. You should point your web server (Apache or Nginx) to a `public` directory inside Laravel roo directory and then you should use URLs like this:

```
/task
```

instead of this:

```
/quickstart/public/task
```

For Apache's `httpd.conf` configuration file you can use settings like these:

```
DocumentRoot "/user/htdocs/public"
<Directory "/user/htdocs/public">
```

Don't forget to reboot web server after that.

Comment: where is httpd.conf file? My local root directiry is /var/www/html

Comment: It really depends on a distro you use. Try to run `httpd -v` command, it should show you a pass to config file.

Comment: after running the httpd -v I got followingsubhash@subhash-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ httpd -v
No command 'httpd' found, did you mean: 
 Command 'http' from package 'httpie' (universe)
 Command 'https' from package 'httpie' (universe)
 Command 'xttpd' from package 'xtide' (universe)
httpd: command not found

Comment: Try to find it with a `find` command http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786606/find-all-files-matching-name-on-linux-system-and-search-with-them-for-text